# A word describing a word of mixed-language etymology

Tags: word-request, etymology

I am looking for a word that denotes a word composed of at least two parts, at least one of which is from a different language than the other(s); a word with mixed etymology.

An example is `antimatter` where we have the Greek prefix for **not**, `anti-`, with the Latin word for **substance**, `māteria`.

If pressed, I might suggest "bastard word" for these specimen, but it does not sound quite right. Other examples of such words are also much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, a [**loanblend**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loanblend):

> a word some of whose constituents are native and others of foreign origin—called also hybrid

Strangely, although Merriam-Webster's definition of **loanblend** does indeed refer to *hybrid*, none of the senses that it lists for *hybrid* compare. Also strangely, while I found this in Merriam-Webster, I did not find it in Oxford or some other main dictionaries. (But I was trying to locate something that wasn't just in Wikipedia . . .)

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia, one term for this is a [hybrid word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word). The concept is briefly discussed [here](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/the-monstrous-indecency-of-hybrid-etymology/) and [here](https://oikofuge.com/hybrid-words/). Ask Metafilter has a [more specific question](https://ask.metafilter.com/62063/Whats-a-word-meaning-having-mixed-Greek-and-Latin-roots) with some other possibilities.

Comment: Indeed, and a fine list of examples as well. I thought of `hypervisor` as I was waiting for your answer, but I would never have thought of some of the others :).

Comment: One example you may not have thought of is `@Chemomechanics`, from (medieval) Latin `alchimia` and Greek `mēhkhanikos` ;)

Answer (score 2):

"Macaronic", of mixed foreign and native etymology.
See [the Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/macaronic)
or [the American Herritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=macaronic).

Comment: Your answer should have a link to where this word is defined (see how the other answers have done it).

Comment: OK, how's that?